# Forcing static linkage using CMake on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, cmake, static-libraries

I want to compile my code into a single standalone `EXE` without any `DLLs` on Windows.

My `CMakeLists.txt` looks as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
set(TARGET_NAME "Windows_Static_Compilation_Test")
project(${TARGET_NAME})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(IS_LINUX_BUILD "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")

find_package(Catch2 CONFIG REQUIRED)

# We need Boost
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem REQUIRED) # iostreams removed
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Always compile loguru with streams
add_compile_definitions(LOGURU_WITH_STREAMS)

include_directories(${TARGET_NAME} include)

add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} main.cpp)

if(WIN32)
    add_definitions("-DCURL_STATICLIB")
endif()

# We need cURL for web requests
# find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

# We need zlib for compression
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)

if (${IS_LINUX_BUILD})
    # Link against the dependency of loguru
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} pthread)
endif ()

# Link against zlib
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES})

# Link against Catch2
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} Catch2::Catch2)

# Link against cURL
# target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} CURL::libcurl)

# Link against Boost
target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

My `main.cpp` looks as follows:

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER

#include "catch.hpp"

#include <loguru.cpp>
#include <zlib.h>
// #include <curl/curl.h>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

/* #include <ostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

namespace io = boost::iostreams;
*/

TEST_CASE("Test") {
    LOG_S(INFO) << "Hello from loguru";
    LOG_S(INFO) << "zlib version: " << ZLIB_VERSION;
    // curl_easy_init();
    /* io::stream_buffer<io::file_sink> buf("log.txt");
    std::ostream out(&buf); */
    REQUIRE(true);
}

int main(const int argument_count, char *arguments[]) {
    const auto program_file_size = file_size(arguments[0]);
    LOG_S(INFO) << "Program file size: " << program_file_size;
    const auto result = Catch::Session().run(argument_count, arguments);
    return result;
}
```

However, if I compile in `Release` mode, I get a `Boost` `DLL` despite having specified static linkage in the `CMakeLists.txt`:
[image]

If I furthermore depend on `cURL` I will get e.g. a `libcurl.dll` despite the `add_definitions("-DCURL_STATICLIB")`.

I'm using [`vcpkg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vcpkg) to install libraries via the `x64-windows-static` triplet to get static versions of the libraries.

How can I make sure all libraries are statically linked into the final executable? Do I need to tweak my [`CMakeSettings.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmakesettings-reference)?

Setting `VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET` to `x64-windows-static` causes:

```
Error   LNK2038 mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease' in main.cpp.obj    D:\Cpp\Windows-Static-Compilation-Test\out\build\x64-Release\Windows-Static-Compilation-Test    D:\Cpp\Windows-Static-Compilation-Test\out\build\x64-Release\boost_filesystem-vc140-mt.lib(path_traits.obj) 1
```

Other than `Boost` causing this error, the other libraries are statically linked which is great.

More details regarding the issue with statically linking to Boost [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/16049).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add those two arguments to "cmake build" command:
-DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows-static
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Tools/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake

By adding "DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET" argument you ensure to use the static installed packages.